# Returning array from Raku and C function does not match in nativecall

Tags: c, raku, rakudo, nativecall

I was looking to call a C function https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/nmath/rmultinom.c#L47 from Raku.
For this I have defined Raku function as

```
use NativeCall;
constant RMATH = "./Rmath.dll";
multi set_seed(uint32, uint32)
    is native( RMATH ) { * };
multi set_seed(UInt() $a, UInt() $b) is export {
    set_seed(my uint32 $ = $a, my uint32 $ = $b)
}
sub rmultinom(int32, CArray[num64], int32, CArray[int32])
    is native( RMATH ) { * }; 

sub raku_rmultinom($n , $size, @prob is copy) is export {
    @prob = @prob.map: {$_.Num};
    my $prob = CArray[num64].new(@prob);
    my $ints = CArray[int32].allocate($size);
    rmultinom($n, $prob, $size, $ints);
    return $ints.list
}
```

A call

```
my @prob = [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.1];
set_seed(123,456);
say raku_rmultinom(100, 5, @prob);
```

gives

```
(9 29 49 13 0)
```

*conformant* with C code:

```c
#define MATHLIB_STANDALONE 1
#include "Rmath.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int draws = 100;
    int classes = 5;
    int vals[classes];
    double probs[4] = {0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.1};

    set_seed(123, 456);
    rmultinom(draws, probs, classes, vals);

    for(int j=0; j < classes; j++) {
        printf("Count of class %i drawn: %i\n", j, vals[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```c
Count of class 0 drawn: 9
Count of class 1 drawn: 29
Count of class 2 drawn: 49
Count of class 3 drawn: 13
Count of class 4 drawn: 0
```

But when I increase size to `10`, see example below, the output seems weird:

```raku
my @prob = [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.1];
set_seed(123,456);
say raku_rmultinom(100, 10, @prob);
```

```
(0 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0) # expectation was (9 29 49 13 0 0 0 0 0 0)
```

while in C:

```c
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int draws = 100;
    int classes = 10;
    int vals[classes];
    double probs[4] = {0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.1};

    set_seed(123, 456);
    rmultinom(draws, probs, classes, vals);

    for(int j=0; j < classes; j++) {
        printf("Count of class %i drawn: %i\n", j, vals[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```c
Count of class 0 drawn: 9
Count of class 1 drawn: 29
Count of class 2 drawn: 49
Count of class 3 drawn: 13
Count of class 4 drawn: 0
Count of class 5 drawn: 0
Count of class 6 drawn: 0
Count of class 7 drawn: 0
Count of class 8 drawn: 0
Count of class 9 drawn: 0
```

Is there any issue with implementation of `raku_rmultinom` in my Raku code?

**System info:**
This is done in Windows 10 64-bit. For reproducibility, I have provided the header and dynamic library here:
https://replit.com/@sumankhanal/rakunativecall.

To test C file with the Rmath.h header and library in the **same folder**, move to that directory and run from `cmd` line:

```
gcc -I. -L. <cfile> -lRmath
.\a.exe
```

---

**Or else**, I am the author of this package https://github.com/sumanstats/Statistics which has `raku_rmultinom` available globally, anyone can install and test the output and its behavior.

---

The version of Raku used is as downloaded from https://rakudo.org/dl/rakudo/rakudo-moar-2023.09-01-win-x86_64-msvc.zip; `raku -v` gives:

```
Welcome to Rakudo™ v2023.09.
Implementing the Raku® Programming Language v6.d.
Built on MoarVM version 2023.09.
```

Comment: Tested on Ubuntu 22.04, raku v2022.02: Output is as expected here: `(9 29 49 13 0 0 0 0 0 0)`

Comment: *"and run from cmd line: `gcc -I. -L. <cfile> -lRmath`"* Are you using gcc (not MSVC C compiler) on windows? Is this from a WSL Linux terminal?

Comment: @raiph Once you go to repl.it com please locate `<>` on the lower side at same line as `run`, click it and you will find the attached files on left side.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to wrap my head around `allocate` since it seems to be the function that's somehow provoking the error; I haven't found any documentation for it. How did you decide to use it?

Comment: @HåkonHægland Yes it is  `gcc` as my compiler. I am not using WSL linux terminal, its the plain `cmd` line of windows.

Comment: @jjmerelo The docs [here](https://docs.raku.org/language/nativecall#Arrays) say it was introduced since `Rakudo 2018.05`.

Comment: @Suman thanks. It's not in the index... Anyway, I would go for a bug here, but I can't see what's the difference here between 5 and 10. Have you tried 4, for instance, since there are only so many classes?

Comment: The only issue I'm seeing here  https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/4e6901b4cf5b02d539a29d10b063f84c30e9b63b/src/nmath/rmultinom.c#L71-L72 is that you would be accessing `prob` beyond its last value. When `$size == K == 5` it's probably no big deal, but maybe with K=10 behavior will depend on the compiler. That does not solve your problem, but I think that debugging the C side might help a bit. Simply printing the values of the `rN` array might give you an idea.

Comment: In other words, I'd try `@prob` size to be exactly `$size`. Might or might not be the solution to your problem (which might be a bug after all), but it will avoid nasty side effects.

Comment: @jjmerelo There is no issue with 4. Gives expected output. I was concerned about uniformity of the output regards to 10. After all we are calling `c` function, so what `c` gave, I expected in `raku`.

Comment: Yep, but Raku is a dynamic language, C is static. You need to be very careful with array sizes. There's no problem with 4 because it's exactly the size of the @prob array. 5 is still close. 6 or 7, might give you unpredictable result, which might depend on the compiler.

Comment: @Suman *"Yes it is gcc as my compiler*" Maybe you have installed MSYS2, and have gcc from that in the path: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-install-c-and-cpp-compiler-on-windows/

Comment: In the Raku part, when `$size > +@prob`, you are invoking undefined behaviour (similarly, in the C testing code, when `classes` is greater than number of elements in `probs`, i.e., the second case) because of the access [`prob[k]`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/nmath/rmultinom.c#L72) in the C library as `k` goes up to `$size` yet `@prob` doesn't have that many elements. A remedy could be making sure `@prob` has enough elemets with 0s padded, e.g., via `@prob.append(0 xx $size - @prob);` in `raku_rmultinom`.

Comment: @HåkonHægland I installed `gcc` from https://github.com/brechtsanders/winlibs_mingw/releases/download/13.2.0mcf-16.0.6-11.0.1-ucrt-r2/winlibs-x86_64-mcf-seh-gcc-13.2.0-mingw-w64ucrt-11.0.1-r2.zip and added it in PATH. Once dynamic library is used, should that be a problem? My understanding is I am **using** the same dynamic library in `c` and `raku`.

Comment: (I realize @jjmerelo already suggested what I wrote, but this is a bug in the user code, not in Rakudo.)

Comment: @MustafaAydın right, but might explain the unpredictable behavior, i. e., the fact that it works with some compilers/OSs, does not with others. At any rate, could be a good idea to check.

Comment: @MustafaAydın OK. Thank you. What could be the *right* wrapper for calling `rmultinorm` from raku? Would `@prob.append(0 xx $size - @prob)` be enough? Because it again fails in `my @prob = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.2];
set_seed(123,456);
say raku_rmultinom(3, 5, @prob);` when expected is `(0, 0, 1, 0, 2)` it gives `(9 14 34 23 20)` (totally unexpected).

Comment: @Suman You have a hard-coded 100 in the `raku_rmultinorm` function in its penultimate line

Comment: @MustafaAydın Oops. Fixed. I still see discrepancy. Consider this [raku](https://pastebin.com/M0AKzjWB) and [c](https://pastebin.com/GXgQvD8i) code. Debugging in the `C` code, before calling `rmultinom(draws, probs, classes, vals);` line but after `set_seed`, the vals are already populated. This is from debugger`(gdb) p vals
$1 = {1, 0, 1635325728, 32758, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6290992, 0, 1635326112, 32758}` which after calling `rmultinom` are `(gdb) p vals
$3 = {0, 0, -1, 32758, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6290992, 0, 1635326112, 32758}`. (cont.)

Comment: (contd.) The outputs from two (see the links) are different. Is it expected? From the line https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/nmath/rmultinom.c#L73 it sets rN[k]=-1 if any `prob`> 1 which in our code is that explains `-1`, but other values don't match. Is it unexpected behavior that's expected? Looks like its the return before altering other values of `rN`.

Comment: @Suman This is expected behaviour: in C, when you declare a variable but not initialize it, it will be given a "garbage" value, i.e., whatever value happens to sit at the memory address appointed to the variable. For arrays, all of its elements will have who-knows-what values like 1635326112 or 32758 or 0 as you observed. In Rakudo's NativeCall, on the other hand, the [`.allocate`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/main/lib/NativeCall/Types.rakumod#L219) method happens to initialize the array elements with 0s explicitly, so you have all 0s (except for that -1) there.

Comment: (.allocate initializes them with nqp::create(int32), i.e., a new int32 object, which, unlike the nonnative Int of Raku, [has the default value of 0](https://docs.raku.org/language/nativetypes).)

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me with such explanation. Looks like `@prob.append(0 xx $size - @prob)` is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's worth summing up what happened in this SO.

First, what @Suman (the asker) concluded (in the comments below their question) was what "looks like" the answer:

```
@prob.append(0 xx $size - @prob)
```

---

This reflects the fact that for this Q, as is sometimes the case when bridging the gap between C and Raku, the problem is mismatches between Raku norms (which generally make sense when coding in Raku) and C norms (which generally make sense when coding in C) rather than problems with the technology on either side. Some excerpts from the comment exchange are illustrative of the process of getting to the bottom of such a mismatch:

> Tested on Ubuntu ... Output is as expected here: `(9 29 49 13 0 0 0 0 0 0)`

> Raku is a dynamic language, C is static. You need to be very careful with array sizes. There's no problem with `4` because it's exactly the size of the `@prob` array.

> In the Raku part, when `$size > +@prob`, you are invoking undefined behaviour ... A remedy could be making sure `@prob` has enough elements with `0`s padded, e.g., via `@prob.append(0 xx $size - @prob);` in `raku_rmultinom`.

> in C, when you declare a variable but not initialize it, it will be given a "garbage" value, i.e., whatever value happens to sit at the memory address appointed to the variable. For arrays, all of its elements will have who-knows-what values like `1635326112` or `32758` or `0` as you observed. In Rakudo's NativeCall, on the other hand, the `.allocate` method happens to initialize the array elements with `0`s explicitly, so you have all `0`s (except for that `-1`) there.